# Searching for an object

Tags: python

This is how I have been searching for objects in python. Is there any more efficient (faster, simpler) way of doing it?

Obs: A is a known object.

```
for i in Very_Long_List_Of_Names:
    if A == My_Dictionary[i]:
        print: "The object you are looking for is ", i
        break
```

Comment: Your code will always break, so it doesn't really iterate through the long list. Perhaps you meant to indent "break" one step more?

Comment: PEP8: Very_Long_List_Of_Names, My_Dictionary. Ugh.

Comment: it seems you need the reverse dictionary (value -> key), is it acceptable to build it?

Comment: @Mattias, you are right I lost an indent there when typing. @Tokland, this is just a mockup of a real code problem; I will try playing with a reverse dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one liner would be: `(i for i in List_of_names if A == My_dictionary[i]).next()`.

This throws a `KeyError` if there is an item in `List_of_names` that is not a key in `My_dictionary` and a `StopIteration` if the item is not found, else returns the key where it finds A.

Comment: I like this generator+next, but in my apps I prefer to build a first() so it looks more meaningful: first(i for i in List_of_names if A == My_dictionary[i])

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for an object in the values of a Python dictionary.

If you simply want to check for its existence (as in, you don't really care to know which key maps to that value), you can do:

```
if A in My_Dictionary.values():
    print "The object is in the dictionary"
```

Otherwise, if you do want to get the key associated with that value:

```
for k, v in My_Dictionary.iteritems():
    if v == A:
        print "The object you are looking for is ", k
        break
```

**EDIT:** Note that you can have multiple keys with the same value in the same dictionary. The above code will only find the first occurence. Still, it sure beats having a huge list of names. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have you're using the dictionary incorrectly if you're searching through all the keys looking for a specific value.

If `A` is hashable, then store A in a dictionary with its values as `i`.

```
d = {A: 'a_name'}
```

If `My_Dictionary` is not huge and can trivially fit in memory, and, `A` is hashable, then, create a duplicate dictionary from it:

```
d = dict((value, key) for key, value in My_Dictionary.iteritems())
if A in d:
    print "word you're looking for is: ", d[A]
```

Otherwise, you'll have to to iterate over every key:

```
for word, object_ in My_Dictionary.iteritems():
    if object_ == A:
        print "word you're looking for is: ", word
```

Comment: "reversing" key and values in a new dictionary means that duplicate values will overwrite each other. But the original post also have the problem of not knowing which one of the values it hits first.

Comment: You're right, but, in my defense, I figured that assumption was made given the way relima wrote his for loop.